# How can associated or integrate nDepends with TFS

Tags: ndepend

Can anyone tell me how can i integrate nDepends  in existing project TFS i am using VS2010.?

I have found a solution nDepends documentation but i am unable to understand completely.

anyone having any idea to show me with configuration to integrate nDepends with my Existing TFS project.

I have just started to understand nDepends.

Thanks
Amit